# PyMongo: How to update_many without using update operators?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

What's the best way to update multiple documents when the modification cannot be directly expressed using update operators?

This is what I have so far:

```
def modify_doc(doc):
    // modify doc in place
    return modified_doc

for doc in db.collection.find({}):
    mod_doc = modify_doc(doc)
    collection.replace_one({'_id': mod_doc._id}, new_doc)
```

I was also considering:

```
def get_update_instructions(doc):
    mod_doc = modify_doc(doc)
    // take diff between doc and mod_doc and create update_instructions
    return update_instructions

for doc in db.collection.find({}):
    update_instructions = get_update_instructions(doc)
    collection.update_one({'_id': mod_doc._id}, update_instructions)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: It's hard to tell without really understanding the requirements. Its possible your initial assumption of needing to modify all of the docs in this manner is incorrect.

Comment: You're right. I didn't post working code because I'm more interested in generally applicable design patterns than a specific solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still apply bulk updates which is kinda similar to performing batch transactions in SQL databases (but without rollback so be careful). This is subtly documented but it is via the `bulk_write` method present on `pymongo.Collection` objects. The basic methodology is to manually aggregate your update operations by creating UpdateOne instances and putting them into a list. Then when you are ready to write to the db you call `bulk_write`

as a rudimentary example based on your current code:

```
from pymongo import UpdateOne

def modify_doc(doc):
    // modify doc in place
    return modified_doc

bulk_updates = []

for doc in db.collection.find({}):
    mod_doc = modify_doc(doc)
    bulk_updates.append(UpdateOne({'_id': mod_doc._id}, mod_doc))

db.collection.bulk_write(bulk_updates)
```

For more Operations you can use with the bulk_write method here is the documentation link: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/operations.html